# How do I get this header image to scale correctly?

Tags: html, css, image, header, scaling

I am trying to get this header image to scale to whatever size I need but it's not doing it exactly. Everything on the site is scaling, but the image is like one or two pixels off on the right side.

```
<div id="headerpic"><img style="width:100%" src="images/logo2.jpg"></div>
```

Is the html

```
#headerpic
{
position: relative;
height: 100%;
margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Is the CSS

It looks alright except for the few pixels hanging over. I suspect it might be because of the black border around it, but border="0" does nothing to remove that. Anyone have a clue? Cus I don't...

Comment: It's kind of hard to tell without access to `images/logo2.jpg`

Comment: if possible can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can play on! with your current code.

Comment: add this to your css it might fix the problem. * { padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border you are talking about might be on the image, then you can try putting something like

```
#headerpic img {
    border: none; 
}
```

into your CSS. See example on this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cx7Ge/).

Anyway, it would be helpful if you included a [jsfiddle reconstruction of your problem with some more of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Thanks, the border: none added to the style part worked. That was the problem. I assumed if the border was part of the image, then there would be no issue, because it would fit to the pixel scale specifications. But since the browser is adding it in, it throws it off 2 pixels in addition to the picture itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS like this.

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

The image should then scale to fit the dimensions of its parent container.

Recommendation from [webdesignerwall.com](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries)